# PostgreSQL server does not start

Tags: postgresql

I instal pg server and tools using standard package from official site( MacOs ).

Everything worked fine, until I changed a configure file - postgresql.conf.

```
shared_buffers = 32MB To shared_buffers = 128MB
```

Then, when I restarted the system, server does not starts.

Why it's happens?

May be because file owner is changed? Was postgres - became 'root'. If Yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: Most probably it's the file ownership. Make sure the postgres user is allowed to read it. AFAIK MacOS is "just" a unix so using `chown` should do the job.

Comment: I change file owner/group/permission, but server do not want to start(. If i tried to start server from terminal i get next message 'code' $ /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/postgres 
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
 'code'

Comment: Then specify the location as mentioned in the message.

Comment: At last server started) The problem was not only in permissions of .conf file, but in size of shared_buffers too. In consol I found a message from server 'could not create shared memory segment invalid argument postgres' when it try to start. So I decide to commented this param in .conf file - and server started working.  So I will reed tutorial about cash size more carefully, before change some params :). If any body gives additional informations about cache size of postgre server, and  how it affect to speed of working, I will be very grateful. Thanks

Comment: 128MB should not be any problem for the size of the shared buffers. There must something else going wrong

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to [`adjust your kernel settings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/kernel-resources.html) to match the new size you requested.

Comment: Thanks, I will study this article. But if I will return the value of params - server still does not start.

Comment: For 128MB shared buffers, a change in the kernel parameters should not be necessary